# Pdf printer driver C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am looking for a free open source .Net based (prefer C#) pdf driver. Any idea where I can download one?

Comment: My requirement is : users should be able print any kind of document using this pdf driver. Once driver write the file into a temp pdf file. I need to execute my .exe file and load it in my UI.

Comment: any reason why you put that as a comment rather than editing your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pdf Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)

> PDFCreator easily creates PDFs from any Windows program. Use it like a printer in Word, StarCalc or any other Windows application.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a pdf driver. My requirement is : users should be able print any kind of document using this pdf driver. Once driver write the file into a temp pdf file. I need to execute my .exe file and load it in my UI.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to use created PDF file inside of your C# application, then the easiest way is to generate PDF inside this application. Then you don't need to monitor a temp folder for a new file created.
To generate PDF inside of your application you will need a PDF-generating library for C#.
For example, [PDFFlow](https://go.pdfflow.io/generate_pdf_lib) library. You can generate all the elements of PDF document (text element, paragraph, image, inline image, line, table, page number, header/footer, etc...), so you can construct "any kind of document", as you said.
Hope, this idea will help.